# Get Joomla session value in wordpress

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla Website. I have also installed a wordpress in the root folder of my joomla website. ie joomla/wordpress . I am not able to get the session value set in joomla in wordpress. How do i get the session value set in joomla in wordpress and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has its own session handling, so the only way is to use the Joomla functions like this:

```
define( '_JEXEC', true );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
```

To get Joomla user id:

`$user =& JFactory::getUser();`
`$user_id = $user->get('id');`

and to get user session id use:

`$session = & JFactory::getSession();`
`$session_id = $session->getId();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when i tried it, i got the following error in my blog 'Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\saw_intranet\blog\wp-includes\cache.php on line 93' ...... what should i do now...Appreciate your response

Comment: $user must be null then, did you login to joomla first?

Comment: No i did log in .....in cache.php the following function is throwing error. "function wp_cache_get($id, $flag = '') {
    global $wp_object_cache;

    return $wp_object_cache->get($id, $flag);
}"

Comment: I guess something in word press is not initialized properly. I don't know why you get that error.

Comment: Did you try this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/blog/6659